# How to install a new pvc line on a fridge to an existing small plastic line?

Tags: refrigerator

What do I need to get this going? a kit? first time installing or connecting myself.  any help will be great appreciated.  I have a pac lined tubing, but nothing else.

Comment: Welcome Mike.  Can you be more specific?  You already have a pipe coming out of the wall to supply the fridge with water?  What size is it? You can edit your question to add any more detail to it.

Comment: What's pac lined? Need the model of your fridge or preferably, pictures of the inlets, your line and the parts that came with it.

Comment: sorry guys. I have a plastic tube from the floor very small, I am not too sure of the diameter. but very thin. this was used with my old fridge for the ice and water.

Comment: I meant to say I got a PVC tubing with the new fridge.  but no connectors.  so basically I need to attach the small plastic tubing I have running from the floor to the new fridge connectors.  what do I need for that? basically.  Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question with the correction?

Answer (score 3):

Most refrigerators come with either a 1/4" plastic or copper tube or a male hose thread (just like your garden hose spigot) inlet.

If you are connecting 1/4" tube to 1/4" tube, you need a compression coupling:
[image: compression coupling]

The inserts slide into the plastic tube to prevent it from collapsing when you tighten the fittings.

If you have a hose thread connector you will need an adapter:[image]

The picture does not show the hose washer, you need that too.

Comment: Actually, if you look close, the picture **does** include the hose washer!

Answer (score 1):

A compression fitting will work, but these are much easier to work with.

[image]

You just push the ends of the tubing into the connector and you're done.  They are generally sold as push-to-connect fittings.  This is likely the right part at Home Depot.  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-1-4-in-Plastic-O-D-x-O-D-Coupling-PL-3000/100165880