# Home Repair of Refrigerator Waterline

Tags: plumbing, repair, leak, refrigerator

I have an 10 year old LG refrigerator ([model LRFD25850ST](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-LRFD25850ST)). The white polyethylene waterline running from the refrigerator water pump up the back of the refrigerator is leaking about half-way up. It feeds both the ice maker and in-door water dispenser, but it runs *through* the foam insulation first, so a complete replacement is not practical at this time.

I would like to see if I can repair or splice it.

[image]

That writing on the tube reads:

> DMT PE TUBE 0.D5/16"XI.DO.216" 70F 170P= NSF-51 & NSF-61 04EH10 05-1

What is the best way to repair this waterline?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to install a new pvc line on a fridge to an existing small plastic line?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49846/how-to-install-a-new-pvc-line-on-a-fridge-to-an-existing-small-plastic-line). If yours is leaking in a non-accessible area somewhere inside the fridge then it's not one but this shows the parts you might need.

Comment: The writing on the tube says that the material is polyethylene (PE) with an outside diameter of 5/16" (O.D5/16), and an inside diameter of 0.216" (I.D0.216"). It is rated for up to 170PSI (170P=) at 70°F (70F). It meets the requirements for plastic used with food (NSF-51) as well as drinking water (NSF-61). I believe that DMT is the manufacture.

Comment: Is this tube part that came with the fridge or is it the water line that connects the fridge to your domestic water? I ask because the 5/16 seems like an odd size. Have you looked at this: http://www.appliancepartspros.com/lg-tube-pe-5210ja3004k-ap4445606.html

Comment: 5/16" OD compression coupling- any decent plumbing shop. 1/4" is the "standard" for the house supply, but this sounds like an OEM tube that is "part" of the refrigerator; ("... it runs through the foam insulation first..."), so not uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need a plastic quick coupling.**  Go to a professional plumbing supplier and buy a 5/16 x 5/16 Parker fitting. These are similar to Sharkbite fittings, but plastic and about half the size of the smallest Sharkbite. They come in 1/4, 5/16, 3/8 and 7/16.  A number of companies such as Celcon and John Guest make them, but Parker invented them so like Hoover for a vacuum, they are called 'Parkers'. 
Simply cut your pipe right at the leak with a very sharp craft knife then fit each end into the straight fitting.

Comment: Beautiful. I bought a Watts "Quick-Connect coupling" for refrigerator, 5/16  OD, cut the existing line just above and below the crack, pushed the two ends into the coupler, and gave it a little tug to seat it. Voila; instant repair. Total time: 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

A trip to the local hardware or home center should provide you with the tubing and fittings you need. If you shut off the valve you can cut out a section to bring with you. You'll need a couple of fittings to connect the new to the old. Bear in mind I would consider this a temporary repair. What ever caused the section to fail be it age or vibration likely effected all the tubing so total replacement is what I would recommend.

Comment: The tube label says that the outside dimension is 5/16 which seems like an odd size. Most hardware centres would carry 1/4 or 3/8 outside dimension fittings, not sure how available 5/16 fittings will be.

Comment: @pdd - The hard part might be finding 5/16" with the sleeve inserts you need for plastic so that it doesn't squish. 5/16" is usually metallic automotive brake line which doesn't need them.

Comment: @Mazura - Completely agree. I think this portion of tube is part of the fridge. I've asked this in the question comments as well as provided a link to what might be the replacement tube part.

Answer (score 0):

The tube comes in through the fridge into the filter system pull the filter and one screw and the hole tube can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older link but I've had the same situation with my lg refrigerator.  it is a line that comes from the solenoid up the back of the fridge into the filter you might as will just replace the whole thing is I have splice mine a few times and it is continually sprung a leak and other places.   I think it is ridiculous that LG put a line in the back of the refrigerator that is rated for 70°F .   It's not a hard fix